# How to plot bar graph with ggplotly in order of the rows?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)
    library(plotly)

    UnemployementRate <- read_excel("data/UnemployementRate.xlsx") 
    
    for (i in seq( 1, length( UnemployementRate$Country)/2 )) {
      UnemployementRate$Country[i*2] <- UnemployementRate$Country[ (i*2-1)]  
    }

UnemployementRate <- UnemployementRate%>%
  select("Country", "Sex", "2019") 
   

 p22 <- ggplot(UnemployementRate, aes(x = Country,y=`2019`, fill = Sex)) +
          geom_bar(position="identity", stat="identity",alpha = 0.6,color = "black")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
      labs(title="Unemployed Ratio of Women and Man (2019)", 
           y="Unemployment (%)", x="", 
           caption="Source: OECD") +
      scale_fill_manual("Sex", values = c("Men" = "red", "Women" = "grey"))
    
    fig1 <- ggplotly(p22)
    fig1
```

Data i use https://s6.dosya.tc/server2/dt0wvy/UnemployementRate.xlsx.html

I ordered(by the 2019 column)
my data like this

(after  manipulate my data it looks like this )

[image]

but it still show like this (in alphabetical order)

[image]

And when i use reOrder

```
p22 <- ggplot(UnemployementRate, aes(x =reorder(Country, -`2019`),y=`2019`, fill = Sex)) +
...
```

[image]

Sorting is right but when I arrive on the map with the mouse,
the old Country text is changing to reorder(Country, -`2019`)

I want both the chart to be sorted as well as want the text there to be Country.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Include output of `dput(UnemployementRate)` to your post. We can't copy data from an image.

Comment: Try with `UnemployementRate$Country <- reorder(UnemployementRate$Country, -UnemployementRate$`2019`)`. Then use `aes(x = Country, ...`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you very much for your help it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a little more complicated than @Stefan's above (which I recommend), but here is another way.

First, the data is sorted by creating a new column with the max for each Country, then the data are sorted (or `dplyr::arrange`) using the new max column and the `2019` column.

```
pp22 <- UnemployementRate %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Country) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(mx = max(`2019`)) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(mx), desc(`2019`)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-mx) 

# Next, get the unique country names, so that it can be used to create the factor for the Country column.
names <- unique(pp22$Country)

# Finally, we encode the Country column as a factor using the order of names.
pp22 <- pp22 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Country = factor(Country, levels=c(names)))
```

For future questions, I highly recommend using `dput` for providing data rather than using a link (as most people will not click on unknown links). In your case, you could use `dput(UnemployementRate[1:10, ])` to give just the first ten rows of data (usually you do not need to provide all of your data).

Comment: pp22 <- UnemployementRate %>%
dplyr::group_by(Country) %>%
...

When i use these codes and plot my graph with my new pp22 data, my problem has been solved, everything I want took place thank you for that.
But when i create names and update my data, All values ​​in the country column are getting NA. So I didn't use the lines there